# Converting a MySQL table from Columns to Rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, transpose

I have several large tables of data that need the columns converted into rows of data with the column name as dats in a field.  I can do this in Excel using a consolidation pivot table but the tables I have are to large for Excel.  Some have as many as 210 colums with 2300 rows of data while others have 20 columsn and 150,000 rows.

I have uploaded a sample in a spreadsheet for viewing on box.com or in Google Docs.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArwEcGYwGw7kdHZya2haVDRvZ0xIM0kzRXRHZ2pQM1E

https://www.box.com/s/199ce71828c320472b57

I am looking for a repeatable process that will allow me to do this for 25 tables, with miner changes to the SQL Code, before I merge them all into one larger table which will have the LOGRECNO and COLUMN ID fields being used to add additional information to the data when it is queried.

Any help on the best way to do this in MySQL would be greatly appreciates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

The following should be a repeatable process with minimal changes:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('select LOGRECNO, '
      '''',
      COLUMN_NAME,
      ''' col, ', column_name, ' as value from yourtable'
    ) separator '  union all '
  ) INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'yourtable'
  and column_name <> 'LOGRECNO';

set @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' Order by 1, 2');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5bb14/38)

Answer (score 0):

This is pivot table problem.

Here is nice tutorial with fast and dynamic solution:
http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf